# Pact consumer test in Go. Issue with dsl.Match function

Tags: go, pact, pact-go

I am writing a Pact consumer test in Go. When I define the interaction I need to add the expected response object. The provider service is written in PHP and this is the response I am expecting:

```php
return  [
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => [
                'configuration' => Associative Array,
                'undeploy_configuration' => Associative Array,
                'meta_data' => Associative Array,
                'undeploy_lora_app_key' => String,
            ],
        ];
```

This is the object I created in Go to represent the response I should get:

```golang
deviceConfigurationResponse := dsl.Like(map[string]interface{}{
        "status": "success",
        "data": dsl.Like(map[string]interface{}{
            "configuration": dsl.MapMatcher{
                "config1": dsl.String("value1"),
                "config2": dsl.String("value2"),
            },
            "undeploy_configuration": dsl.MapMatcher{
                "undeploy1": dsl.String("value3"),
                "undeploy2": dsl.String("value4"),
            },
            "meta_data": dsl.MapMatcher{
                "meta1": dsl.String("info1"),
                "meta2": dsl.String("info2"),
            },
            "undeploy_lora_app_key": dsl.String("example_undeploy_lora_app_key"),
        }),
    })
```

However when I run the test I get this error:

```bash
--- FAIL: TestGetDeviceConfiguration (1.79s)
panic: match: unhandled type: interface {} [recovered]
        panic: match: unhandled type: interface {}
```

This is the full code:

```golang
func TestGetDeviceConfiguration(t *testing.T) {
    // Create Pact client
    pact := &dsl.Pact{
        Consumer: "consumer",
        Provider: "provider",
        PactDir:  "./pacts",
    }

    defer pact.Teardown()

    deviceConfigurationResponse := dsl.Like(map[string]interface{}{
        "status": "success",
        "data": dsl.Like(map[string]interface{}{
            "configuration": dsl.MapMatcher{
                "config1": dsl.String("value1"),
                "config2": dsl.String("value2"),
            },
            "undeploy_configuration": dsl.MapMatcher{
                "undeploy1": dsl.String("value3"),
                "undeploy2": dsl.String("value4"),
            },
            "meta_data": dsl.MapMatcher{
                "meta1": dsl.String("info1"),
                "meta2": dsl.String("info2"),
            },
            "undeploy_lora_app_key": dsl.String("example_undeploy_lora_app_key"),
        }),
    })

    // Define the expected interaction with the provisioning-service
    value := "123456789"
    pact.
        AddInteraction().
        Given("Device configuration exists for the given device ID").
        UponReceiving("A request to get device configuration").
        WithRequest(dsl.Request{
            Method:  "GET",
            Path:    dsl.String(fmt.Sprintf("/api/prov/state/%s/configuration", value)),
            Headers: dsl.MapMatcher{"Accept": dsl.String("application/json")},
        }).
        WillRespondWith(dsl.Response{
            Status:  200,
            Headers: dsl.MapMatcher{"Content-Type": dsl.String("application/json")},
            Body:    dsl.Match(deviceConfigurationResponse),
        })

    // Test the OnSessionEstablished function
    var test = func() error {
        cache := new(CacheMock)
        deviceConfigGetter := new(DeviceConfigGetterMock)

        _, err := GetDeviceConfiguration(value)

        cache.AssertExpectations(t)
        deviceConfigGetter.AssertExpectations(t)

        return err
    }

    // Verify the interaction with the provider
    var err = pact.Verify(test)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using (`Match`) takes a struct annotated with struct tags (see https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-go#auto-generate-matchers-from-struct-tags) that specify how the various items within the struct should be matched. You are manually providing a structure with the right matchers already, so there is no need to wrap it in `Match` at all.

Something like this should work:

```golang
        WillRespondWith(dsl.Response{
            Status:  200,
            Headers: dsl.MapMatcher{"Content-Type": dsl.String("application/json")},
            Body:    deviceConfigurationResponse,
        })
```